# Google map V3 no resizing the center and also it repeats

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps, responsive-design

I have a problem, this is a responsive map and on resize it doesn 't do auto center and also it repeats
I have tried many solutions on here but nothing works.
Can you advice me
this is my fiddle
**http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/48jTZ/1/**

```
.map - container {
margin: 0
}#map {
min - height: 500px;
}
```

[image: when resized it doesn't fit and I don't see the pins]

[image: not all 3 pins are visible]

[image: fiddle when i resize]

Comment: AutoCenter() is only called once.

Comment: What do you mean by "it repeats"?

Comment: Mr. Praveen managed to solve it..thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the idle or bounds_changed event listener on the map to call your AutoCenter function again:

http://jsfiddle.net/48jTZ/3/

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
    AutoCenter();
});
```

You actually don't need to call AutoCenter anywhere else anymore.

**Edit:**

http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/r4wSy/

There you go. It will now use AutoCenter after the map is loaded and then, if the window is resized (I did it with jQuery, but you get the idea).

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    AutoCenter();
});
```

But I find this behavior a bit strange. If the user loads the page, then zooms in to some location, then resizes the window, the map will kind of reset. Well you should know what you want there...

Comment: there is a problem i cant zoom the map and the info window goes out of the bounds

Comment: Well yes, that's right. Because when you zoom or pan, the bounds_changed or idle event get fired as well. You could call the AutoCenter function only on document ready and on window resize.

Comment: One more thing: if by "responsive" you mean that it is intended to be displayed on a mobile device, you might want to look at the orientationchange event as well.

Comment: thanks for the solution dude...but it shows me repeated pin. You can see my edited questions with screenshot

Comment: I cannot reproduce the repeated markers issue unless I zoom out. Please update your fiddle and show us the issue. And what is wrong in screenshots 2 and 3? Need more info.

Comment: Hi...thanks for the reply as you can see i have edited and told you what is the problem with the map. Please tell me what is the right way to go about it. What i want is in any device when page loads all 3 pins should be visible and when a person zoom whenever his mouse is should zoom..I hope im able to make you understand. Thanks a lot for the effort so far

Comment: I don't see any update in your post and your fiddle doesn't implement anything that was suggested so far.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to know is **`bounds_changed`** event, this is triggered whenever the window is resized.  Here add you **`AutoCenter()`** method so that when you resize the window, this will center the markers.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    AutoCenter();
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48jTZ/4/)

Comment: @San I'm glad I was able to help :)

Comment: dude there is a problem i can't zoom and the info window gets cut. What i want is at any viewport all 3 pins should be visible and then later they can zoom if they want

Comment: @San Yes just know I saw this issue, let me fix it